# Using MonadPlus in FRP.Reactive.FieldTrip

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I'm studying FRP at this moment through FieldTrip adaptor. And hit the problem with strange way of frames scheduling and integration. So now I'm trying to build own marker Event for aligning Behaviour stepping.

So...

```
flipflop :: Behavior String
flipflop = stepper "none" (xflip 2) where
    xflip t0 = do
        t <- withTimeE_ (atTime t0)
        return "flip" `mplus` xflop (t+3)
    xflop t0 = do
        t <- withTimeE_ (atTime t0)
        return "flop" `mplus` xflip (t+2)
txtGeom = ((uscale2 (0.5::Float) *%) . utext . show <$>)
main = anim2 (txtGeom . pure flipflop)
```

Questions is:

Why this example leads to memory leak?

Is there safe way to build sequence of events where each next one is scheduled depending on previous?

Comment: For first question: "mplus" - is symmetric, so information about sequence is missed. Using of "listE" gives better results.

Comment: Moving through http://conal.net/blog/posts/trimming-inputs-in-functional-reactive-programming/ , (the dreaded "space-time" leak - I like this term).

Comment: You might be interested by what the synchronous stream languages community has been doing for the last decades to prevent such leaks from being possible at all, for instance http://www.lri.fr/~pouzet/lucid-synchrone/papers/emsoft03.ps.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like joining events in this manner isn't going to work.  Try this instead:

```
import FRP.Reactive
import FRP.Reactive.FieldTrip
import Graphics.FieldTrip
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative


flipflop = stepper "none" $ either (const "flip") (const "flop")
            <$> eitherE (atTimes ((+2) <$> [0,5..])) (atTimes [5,10..])

txtGeom = ((uscale2 (0.5::Float) *%) . utext . show <$>)
main = anim2 (txtGeom . pure flipflop)
```

Unfortunately there's still a space leak in this version, but it's much smaller.  After running for about a minute the total RAM usage was about 9.7MB.

There's also a `flipFlop` function that creates a `Behavior Bool`.  This worked well for the flip-flop, but I didn't see a clean way to add "none" for the first two seconds.

I also tried this

```
flipflop = stepper "none" $ (const "flip" <$> (atTimes ((+2) <$> [0,5..])))
                            `mplus` (const "flop" <$> atTimes [5,10..])
```

which appears to work identically to the first version.

Of course, this doesn't do much for dynamically scheduling in the manner your asking about.  Unfortunately I don't believe this use-case works in Reactive.

I very much admire the work that's produced Reactive, and I want to like it, but it seems to be extremely tricky to reason about.  [This thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/reactive/2010-August/000346.html) from the mailing list is an example of the sort of problem (and solution!) that seems to be common.  Also the "unamb" library (which underlies much of Reactive) exposed a number of very subtle bugs in GHC's threading that played havoc with results until they were fixed around ghc-6.12.  Although that is not in any way the fault of Conal or other Reactive contributors, it made it that much harder to use the framework, particularly with earlier GHC's.

You might try some of the other FRP packages.  Yampa has a sound implementation, and I've heard that [Elerea](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/elerea) is relatively simple to pick up, and it has a nice [demo application](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dow).